# Why after install ubuntu 22.04 alongside windows 10 neither windows 10 or ubuntu 22.04 boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

A few days ago I try to install ubuntu 22.04 alongside windows 10 everything went fine until install end and then I try to boot normally into grub bootloader nothing show. The hardware boot return boot failed and direct me back to the boot menu
My device is toshiba Satellite c660-a205 with BIOS-compatibility no uefi I burn the flash drive with gpt NTFS schama when I try to repair the boot using repair boot tool it return my session is in BIOS-compatibility mode must turn in uefi firmware settings Please help I am stuck at this iusse for two days now

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Your system looks like it is UEFI, are installs UEFI or BIOS? How you boot install media is then how it installs.

Comment: Try using the boot-repair ISO from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiH0LeiteD9AhVISmwGHVlmBLEQFnoECCgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fboot-repair-cd%2Ffiles%2Fboot-repair-disk-64bit.iso%2Fdownload&usg=AOvVaw1H57ItDv_QNIujHI4VuGzb).

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6QwC8гN4KF/